# django-cms eCommerce implement: apphook, plugin

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I have a task to design an eCommerce solution for django-cms. The product must be multilingual (en, Fr). So I have an idea: create an app with product model just contain [price,name,images] then write a plugin to display products on cms page. So **each product** I have to create **a cms page** for it, add product plugin, write a description (using text plugin in language). After that change page language and copy product plugin, write another language description.

May I ask, is this a solution, I can't find another way to do this. I'm new to django-cms. Can you point me the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: https://www.django-cms.org/en/e-commerce/

Comment: it's not multilingual :(

Comment: django-shop (https://www.django-cms.org/en/e-commerce/ ) allows you to define your own Product model. So you could use django-hvad or some other multilingual library to make some fields on the product multilingual.

Comment: @stefanfoulis Can you show me (step by step) how to integrate django-shop to djsngo-cms (or an working example would be great). I'm kinda new to them and got stuck in reading docs

Comment: [This __Satchmo__](http://www.satchmoproject.com/) could be the one you are looking for.